# MYSQL comma base separated select result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I have 4 tables, as below.

Table: **Class**

```
ClassID     |   ClassSTD
--------------------------------
1           |   STD-1<br>
2           |   STD-2
```

Table: **Section**

```
SectionId   |   SectionName | ClassId
--------------------------------------------
1           |   sec-A       | 1
2           |   sec-B       | 1
3           |   sec-C       | 1
4           |   sec-A       | 2
5           |   sec-B       | 2
6           |   sec-C       | 2
```

Table: **Subject**

```
subjectId   |   subjectName
------------------------------------
1           |   Art
2           |   Music
3           |   Play
```

Table **SubjectAllocationToClass**

```
    classId         |   sectionID           |   subjectId   | type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   3(sec-C)            |   1(Art)      | optional
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   2(Music)    | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   2(Music)    | optional
```

Above table "SubjectAllocationToClass" shows distribution of two type of subject (Main and optional) to section for class.
How I can achieve below result from SELECT statement?

```
classSTD |  sectionName | Main subjectName   | Optional subjectName
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
STD-1    |  sec-A       | Art, Music         |
STD-1    |  sec-B       | Art                |  Music
STD-1    |  sec-C       |                    |  Art
```

Comment: Yes it is possible and it is called `GROUP_CONCAT` agg function. The question is what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **GROUP_CONCAT()** function:

Try this:

```
SELECT D.classSTD, 
       C.sectionName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(B.subjectName SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjectName
FROM SubjectAllocationToClass A 
INNER JOIN Subject B ON A.subjectId = B.SubjectId 
INNER JOIN Section C ON A.sectionId = C.SectionId   
INNER JOIN Class D ON A.classID = D.ClassID 
GROUP BY D.ClassID, C.SectionId;
```

**For your another question**

```
SELECT D.classSTD, 
       C.sectionName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(B.subjectName SEPARATOR ', ') AS subjectName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN B.type = 'main' THEN B.subjectName ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ', ') AS mainsubjectName, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN B.type = 'optional' THEN B.subjectName ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ', ') AS optionalSubjectName
FROM SubjectAllocationToClass A 
INNER JOIN SUBJECT B ON A.subjectId = B.SubjectId 
INNER JOIN Section C ON A.sectionId = C.SectionId   
INNER JOIN Class D ON A.classID = D.ClassID 
GROUP BY D.ClassID, C.SectionId;
```

Comment: Why downvote? Give the reason so others can find what is the wrong in my query???

Comment: Can you please help me, I edited the condition in main description

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by `group_concat` like this:

```
select classSTD , SectionName ,  group_concat(`subjectName` separator ',') as `subjectName` 
FROM SubjectAllocationToClass 
INNER JOIN Class ON SubjectAllocationToClass.classId = Class.ClassID 
INNER JOIN Section ON SubjectAllocationToClass.sectionID   = Section.sectionId
INNER JOIN Subject ON SubjectAllocationToClass.subjectID   = Subject .subjectId  
GROUP BY  SubjectAllocationToClass.subjectID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

USE `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
 SELECT  sec.SectionName , cl.classSTD, GROUP_CONCAT(`sub.subjectName`) as `subjectName` FROM SubjectAllocationToClass AS al JOIN Class AS cl ON al.classId = cl.ClassID JOIN Section AS sec ON al.sectionID  = sec.sectionId JOIN Subject AS sub ON al.subjectID   = sub.subjectId  
GROUP BY  al.subjectID;
```